# Trouble printing a certain content within a loop derived from another loop

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've created a vba script to parse the time of different posts defined as `postTime` and thier titles from a webpage. Although the `postTime` is available in the target page, I would like to get it from the landing page and print it with the `postTitle` collected from the target page. I've defined selectors within my script which are able to collect the desired contents. However, my current attempt only prints the `postTime` of a certain post several times whereas I want to print the `postTime` of several posts.

***How can I print an item within a loop derived from another loop?***

My script so far:

```
Sub CollectData()
    Const baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, itemlist$, linklist As Variant
    Dim qualifiedLink$, nlink As Variant, postTime$, postTitle$

    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set post = Html.querySelectorAll(".summary .question-hyperlink")

    For I = 0 To post.Length - 1
        postTime = Html.querySelector(".user-action-time").innerText
        qualifiedLink = baseUrl & Split(post(I).getAttribute("href"), "about:")(1)
        itemlist = itemlist & IIf(itemlist = "", "", " ") & qualifiedLink
    Next I

    linklist = Split(itemlist, " ")

    For Each nlink In linklist
        With Http
            .Open "GET", nlink, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        postTitle = Html.querySelector("h1[itemprop='name'] a").innerText
        ' the following line prints postTime derived from earlier loop
        Debug.Print postTime, postTitle
    Next nlink
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use querySelectorAll and index into it during first loop to ensure you get different post times. I would store these in a collection and access them by index in the 
last loop

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CollectData()
    Const baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, itemlist$, linklist As Variant, i As Long
    Dim qualifiedLink$, nlink As Variant, postTime$, postTitle$
    Dim times As Object
    Set times = New Collection
    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set post = Html.querySelectorAll(".summary .question-hyperlink")

    For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
        postTime = Html.querySelectorAll(".user-action-time").item(i).innerText
        times.Add postTime
        qualifiedLink = baseUrl & Split(post(i).getAttribute("href"), "about:")(1)
        itemlist = itemlist & IIf(itemlist = "", "", " ") & qualifiedLink
    Next i

    linklist = Split(itemlist, " ")
    Dim accessor As Long
    For Each nlink In linklist
        accessor = accessor + 1
        With Http
            .Open "GET", nlink, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        postTitle = Html.querySelector("h1[itemprop='name'] a").innerText
        ' the following line prints postTime derived from earlier loop
        Debug.Print times(accessor), postTitle

    Next nlink
End Sub
```

---

Better yet, store the times in a variable rather than keep using `querySelectorAll` within loop, as this will be more efficient:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CollectData()
    Const baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, itemlist$, linklist As Variant, i As Long
    Dim qualifiedLink$, nlink As Variant, postTime$, postTitle$
    Dim times As Object
    Set times = New Collection
    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set post = Html.querySelectorAll(".summary .question-hyperlink")
    Dim timesList As Object
    Set timesList = Html.querySelectorAll(".user-action-time")
    For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
        postTime = timesList.item(i).innerText
        times.Add postTime
        qualifiedLink = baseUrl & Split(post(i).getAttribute("href"), "about:")(1)
        itemlist = itemlist & IIf(itemlist = "", "", " ") & qualifiedLink
    Next i

    linklist = Split(itemlist, " ")
    Dim accessor As Long
    For Each nlink In linklist
        accessor = accessor + 1
        With Http
            .Open "GET", nlink, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        postTitle = Html.querySelector("h1[itemprop='name'] a").innerText
        ' the following line prints postTime derived from earlier loop
        Debug.Print times(accessor), postTitle

    Next nlink
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to try but could not get the idea. Thanks QHarr.